# Validar al ejecutar una consulta PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, validación

Tengo un problema al intentar validar 2 cantidades antes de hacer un update.

En una tabla tengo 2 columnas, envio datos de un producto mediante un POST con los cuales realiza update a la tabla, pero tengo que validar que la cantidad 1 sea igual a la cantidad 2 (ya tengo 2 validaciones que verifican que el ID y la Cantidad no sean vacías) , ya intente hacerlo pero no he tenido suerte, este es el extracto de mi código con la consulta:

```
 <?php
include('is_logged.php');//Archivo verifica que el usario que intenta acceder a la URL esta logueado
    $id_factura= $_SESSION['id_factura'];
    $numero_factura= $_SESSION['numero_factura'];
if (isset($_POST['id'])){$id=intval($_POST['id']);}
if (isset($_POST['cantidad'])){$cantidad2=floatval($_POST['cantidad']);}
    /* Connect To Database*/
require_once ("../config/db.php");//Contiene las variables de configuracion para conectar a la base de datos
require_once ("../config/conexion.php");//Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos
    //Archivo de funciones PHP
include("../funciones.php");

    $sql2=mysqli_query($con, "select * from detalle_factura where numero_factrura='$numero_factura' and id_producto='$id'" );
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql2))
            $cantidad1=$row["cant_prev"];

    if (!empty($id) and !empty($cantidad) and $cantidad1==$Cantidad2){
        $insert_tmp=mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE detalle_factura SET cant_rem='$cantidad2' WHERE id_producto='$id'");}

    else{
        $errors []= "Las cantidades no concuerdan.".mysqli_error($con);}
```

Solo que no se como llamar la otra cantidad de la tabla que seria la columna "cantidad".

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: en tu codigo no haces referencia en ningun momento a una cantidad2. A te referieres con que sea iguales las dos cantidades? Tambien tienes en tu codigo una cosa muy extraña, $cantidad==$ (el $ esta suelto, sin nombre de variable). Por favor, indenta tu codigo para que sea mas legible.

Comment: Ya actualicé el código e hice mi mejor esfuerzo en identarlo, una disculpa soy muy nuevo en esto.

Comment: Tu código es altamente mejorable en cuanto a la lógica que empleas en él, en cuanto al formato también, que no es una cosa banal: un código bien estilizado no es sólo algo bonito, sino que ayuda a entender el programa y hasta a detectar errores de lógica... Sin embargo, los errores principales son dos: 1º. en PHP los nombres de variable son *case sensitive*. Tú declaras `$cantidad2` y en la comparación del `if` usas `$Cantidad2` (al usar `C` mayúscula, estarás usando una variable que no existe). 2º. Si conviertes una de las variables a `floatval`, convierte también la otra...

Comment: **También**, evalúas una variable que no existe aquí: `!empty($cantidad)`

Comment: facil mi amigo hay varias formas tienes que traer cantidad2 en tu archivo  php y ponerlo en un input hidden por ejemplo y luego  mandarlo a tu archivo , luego ya podras validar si son iguales cantidad y cantidad2

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, con las precisiones que me hicieron con respecto a las variables que estaba manejando ayudaron demasiado, llevaba muchas horas en eso y habia perdido perspectiva, ya hace las validaciones y no permite el update cuando no corresponden, aho solo me falta ver por que no arroja el mensaje de error cuando no son iguales.